# Move shapes with inserted rows where Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Tags: excel, vba, insert, shapes

In a large project I add a large number of shapes at different positions in a Worksheet. Furthermore, I insert a number of rows.

I want the shapes to move with the inserted rows. However, they only do so with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. As soon as ScreenUpdating is set `False`, the shapes stop moving. This of course messes up the results completely.

I cannot reproduce the problem. In this minimal example, the inserted shapes move as expected with the inserted row, although I use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. In my larger program the basically identical procedure fails without ScreenUdating.

```
Sub ShapeTest()

Dim ActiveShape As Shape
Dim ShapeCell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ShapeCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Set ActiveShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, ShapeCell.Left, ShapeCell.Top, ShapeCell.Width, ShapeCell.Height)

ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

**Update**

I have tried `DoEvents` before and after inserting the row, but it didn't change anything. Currently I am using this workaround:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Worksheets("Gantt").Rows(ThisRowGTT).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

This slows down the execution alot - almost as if I would use ScreenUpdating for the entire program.